# UILabel highlighted color attributed string (Apple bug?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` in a custom `UITableViewCell`. This label has an attributed string with multiple text colors/fonts. When the cell becomes highlighted, the attributed text in the label all becomes the same color. More specifically, the text all becomes the same color as the **first character**. The fonts do not change.

I think that this behavior has something to do with the `highlighted` and `highlightedTextColor` properties on `UILabel`. I've tested this by subclassing `UILabel` and overriding `-(BOOL)highlighted;` to always return `NO`. This seems to prevent the color change but I'd like to know if anyone can explain *why* this is happening and if there is a better solution (like one that doesn't involve subclassing UILabel).

Comment: Only the color changes? Not the font?

Comment: It happens because when the cell is highlighted for example, if it didn't change color it would be black text on a blue background which makes it hard to read, i'm guessing its just a coincidence that it turns into the same color as the first character

Comment: @JoshCaswell Correct, only the color. I suspect it's because there is no such thing as a "highlightedTextFont".

Comment: @DavidXu My `highlightedTextColor` is nil. I don't want the color to change. If the entire attributed string is the same color, nothing changes. It's only when I mix colors is this a problem.

Comment: Could this be an Apple bug? I'm testing on iOS 7.1.